# Problems with relative paths in Eclipse.

Tags: eclipse, path, relative-path

I am trying to use relative paths in a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse. I am NOT using them in the Servlet, but in another class that is called by the Servlet. The file I am trying to access to is a property file located in

`MyProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/propertyFile.properties`

I have tried almost every relative path...

```
WebContent/WEB-INF/propertyFile.properties 
/WebContent/WEB-INF/propertyFile.properties
./WebContent/WEB-INF/propertyFile.properties
MyProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/propertyFile.properties
/MyProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/propertyFile.properties
WEB-INF/propertyFile.properties
/WEB-INF/propertyFile.properties
./WEB-INF/propertyFile.properties
```

...and so on...what can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am using Jboss to publish the web application (I forgot to comment).

Answer (score 2):

You nee to understand that file IO read **files**, from the **filesystem**, and relative to the directory from which the JVM (i.e. your web container) is started.

Remember that, once your app is deployed to production, there won't be any MyProject or WebContent folder. That's what exists on your development machine. The only thing that will exist in production is the war file deployed in the application server.

What you actually want is to load a resource, located in the deployed web application (i.e. which is inside your war file).

To do that, you must use [ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29):

```
InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/propertyFile.properties");
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but, as I said I am NOT using these files in the Servlet, so, I cannot use the ServletContext.

Comment: You simply have to pass the servlet context from the servlet to the objectif

Comment: What happens if the file I need is in 'WebContent' but not in 'WEB-INF'?

Comment: You would change the path to "/propertyFile.properties".